# SQL Server script to backup tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there an existing script in SQL (maybe in the First Responder Toolkit or something) that can be used to create backups of certain tables. For example, this is what I would need it to do -

1) A script/function/sproc that takes an array of table names. For example, [`dbo.table1`, `old.table2`]

2) Creates tables with the same name in a different schema. For example, [`new.table1`, `new.table2`]

3) Creates all indexes and constraints found in old tables (step 1) in the new tables (step 2).

Comment: This kind of thing is far more complicated than it seems. Consider foreign keys, they would have to be created in a certain order to ensure that both tables already exist. But this is really off topic here because you are asking for an existing tool to do this.

Comment: Consider partition switching.